# How is algebra generated by a matrix defined?

Tags: modules

I didn't find the exact definition (especially an explicit one).
Let $k$ be a field, $B=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        0 & c  \\
                \end{pmatrix}
$$\in M_2(k)$ a matrix. Let $k[B]$ be the algebra generated by $B$ in $M_2(k)$. Is there an explicit way to write $k[B]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed the subalgebra of $M_2(k)$ generated by the powers of $B$. It is isomorphic to $k[x]/m(x)$, where $m(x)$ is the minimum polynomial of $B$. In your particular case $m(x) = \det(xI - B) = (x-a)(x-c)$ (unless a=c and b=0, in which case it's $x-a$).

Comment: Just to complete the answer, and assuming $B \ne 0$, if $a-c=b=0$, then the algebra is just $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} u & 0\\ 0 & u \end{bmatrix} :u \in k \right\}$. Otherwise it is $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} u + v a & v b\\ 0 & u + v c \end{bmatrix} :u, v \in k \right\}$.